# Uncaught (in promise) SweetAlert: 2nd argument ('undefined') is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert

I'm trying to create a login/logout with React and Sweet Alert, but the it keeps saying that the 2nd argument is invalid and I'm not sure where.
Below the code for the login.
Can anyone spot any error in these functions?
If yes, please let me know.
Cheers

```
import React, {
    useState
} from 'react';
import swal from 'sweetalert';

async function loginUser(credentials) {
    let BaseUrl = 'process.env.MYCREDENTIALS';
        fetch(BaseUrl, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
            })
            .then(data => data.json())      
           }

export default function Signin() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [username, setUserName] = useState();
    const [password, setPassword] = useState();

    const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const response = await loginUser({
            username,
            password
        });

        if ('accessToken') {
            swal("Success", {
                    buttons: false,
                    timer: 1000,
                })
                .then((value) => {
                    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', response['accessToken']);
                    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response['user']));
                    window.location.href = "/profile";
                });
        } else {
            swal("Failed", response.message, "error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wrapping a `fetch` in a new Promise is completely unnecessary; it already returns a Promise.

Comment: And the error means that `response.message` is `undefined`. Have you tried logging the value of `response` or looking at it in the browser debugger?

Comment: Right, I made some changes and I can see the console.log with the data, but then a new error message now reads:  "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accessToken')". Not sure why is not usign the local storage or is that something else?

Comment: Your `loginUser` function looks like it does not return anything.